# Reject pull on branch that does not exist locally

Tags: git

I have a problem that occurs whenever I want to pull, push, rebase or fetch.

Here is a list of branches that I get when I do `git branch -l`:

```
*develop
rel/9.8.x
rel/9.9.x
```

Now previously I had a branch called `origin/rel/9.7.7` that I removed by doing `git branch -D origin/rel/9.7.7` but it still exists remote -

Now when I try to do a pull, push, rebase, or a fetch I get this message:

```
 ! [rejected]        rel/9.7.7 -> origin/rel/9.7.7  (non-fast-forward)
```

I have checked my git config, and nothing in it states anything about 9.7.7 (but some info about the other branches).

What can I do? Where can I look?

Comment: What output do you get when you issue `find .git -name '9.7.7'` from the top level of your git repository?

Comment: This is the result:
.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/origin/rel/9.7.7
.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/rel/9.7.7
.git/refs/remotes/origin/origin/rel/9.7.7
.git/refs/remotes/origin/rel/9.7.7

Comment: Can you also edit in the output of `git remote show origin`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you delete the branch on the remote as well as locally?

```
git push origin :rel/9.7.7
```

Comment: The thing is the branch should exist remote, I just don't want any traces of it locally (if that makes sense). In the future I may have to checkout the branch again.